# KeyError: 0 , while running while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pycharm

I am trying to create a functionality and now my code has been stuck at one point, giving this error:

```
in stochasticUniversalSampling
    if fitness_prob[j] > points[i]:
KeyError: 0
```

I am trying to assign each chromosome a range equal in length to its fitness and a starting point that is after the end point of the previous chromosome (e.g. first chromosome 0-1.53, 2nd chromosome 1.54-2.26, 3rd chromosome 2.27-3.42, etc). Select the chromosomes whose range contains a marker (note that a chromosome may have 2 markers in which case it is chosen twice).

city.txt

```
5
1 823170 415922
2 793699 274913
3 981665 218777
4 878910 431320
5 910125 405907
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: The error message informs you the the value `0` is not a key in your dict.  You failed to provide either an execution trace or the driver program necessary to elicit the error.

Comment: Sure, I will update the issue.

Comment: The line in the error message doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry, I updated that line with your suggestion                   `if fitness_prob[self.population[j]] > points[i]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created `fitness_prob`, you used the values from `self.population` as the keys. But in the `while` loop you're using the indexes of `fitness_prob` as the keys, when you should be using the values. Change:

```
if fitness_prob[j] > points[i]:
```

to

```
if fitness_prob[self.population[j]] > points[i]:
```

Comment: It gets stuck in infinite loop.

Comment: `while len(parents) < N:` will be an infinite loop if you don't add `N` items to `parents`.

Comment: ok, Is there any simpler way to  compare  fitness_prob and points?

Comment: This is a fine way to compare them. I think the problem may be with your logic.

Comment: If the condition isn't satisfied enough times, you'll never get out of the loop.

Comment: True, will try different logic.